# Hyper-V Network Address (MAC) crash

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Hyper-V - Windows 10

When setting up network interfaces, the MAC address
 was mistakenly removed from the vEthernet device (Default Switch).

When further attempts are made to restore the previous settings (return the remote address to its original location) of this network interface, the operating system simply disables this device, the operation of which is directly related to Hyper-V.

I tried the standard Windows 10 troubleshooting procedure, but it did not bring any results.

So the question is. Is there a way to return the network device to normal operation?
If not, will a standard reinstallation of the Hyper-V server help?

Here are some pictures:

[Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngw7A.png)

[Hyper-V Network Configuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC4ds.png)

---

Windows 10 Is A Lab Testing Environment – What If that happens with a Real Host?

Comment: so you are using hyperv on windows 10? what is the business relationship in here and what business environment is affected by this question?